# API Bitfinex question: "key amount should be a decimal string"?

Tags: api, exchange-order, bitfinex, python

I started writing code for the Bitfinex api yesterday and I've been struggling quite a lot with this.
I am using jndok's [python implementation](http://jndok.net/bitfinexapi.html).

I added my pyblic and secret keys and wrote this line of code at the end with python 2.7 on Windows 8:

```
rep = place_order(0.001, 589.0, 'sell', 'limit', exchange='bitfinex')
```

And I thought that would do it but the reply I get 'Key amount should be a decimal string' and the order is not placed.
I also tried to print the reply code I get from the server and it is 400.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 3):

You are submitting a float value. Float values are not totaly accurate:

```
>>> 0.9 
0.90000000000000002
```

Thats why the [specification](https://www.bitfinex.com/pages/api) requires a [Decimal datatype](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal("0.001")
```